# AsyncTask долго соображает в одном Активити

Tags: activity, android-asynctask, android

Добрый день! 
Столкнулся с проблемой, которую никак не могу решить, да и странная она.

У меня есть свой написанный класс SendDate, который я использую для отправки данных на сервер.

В нем есть процедура Send(), которая, собственно, и производит отправку данных.
Вот как это выглядит:

```
public void Send(String process)
    {
        processing = process;
        new SendParamToURL(callBackSend, URL, process).execute(ListParam);
    }
// ОТПРАВКА ДАННЫХ
    static class SendParamToURL extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<SendParam>, String, String>
    {
        private CallBackSendDate listener;
        private String URL;
        private String processing;
        public SendParamToURL(CallBackSendDate listener, String URL, String process){
            this.listener = listener;
            this.URL = URL;
            this.processing = process;
        }
        //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<SendParam>... params)
        {
            try
            {
                DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
                //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
                HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(this.URL);
                //будем передавать два параметра
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params[0].size());
                //передаем параметры из наших текстбоксов
                for(SendParam info : params[0])
                {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(info.name, info.value));
                }
                //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
                postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                //получаем ответ от сервера
                String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
                return response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
                //listener.onError(e.toString());
            }
            return "";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            listener.onReturnAnswer(result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            listener.onSend(processing);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
```

Вот, собственно, как я отправляю данные:

```
public static SendDate SendDateURL;
....
SendDateURL = new SendDate();
SendDateURL.initialize(Url, sendDateCallBack);
...
SendDateURL.ClearParam();
SendDateURL.AddParam("Param1", Value1);
SendDateURL.AddParam("Param2", Value2);
SendDateURL.Send("");
```

Вот парадокс, конкретно данный запрос отрабатывает очень быстро, кроме одной активити.
На одной из активити выполняю данный запрос, процедура доходит до конструктора

```
public SendParamToURL(CallBackSendDate listener, String URL, String process)
```

Дальше идет какое-то провисание по времени, секунд 10-15, а иногда и больше, и уже после мы попадаем в процедуру:

```
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<SendParam>... params)
```

Причем это происходит только на одной активити, на всех остальных все прекрасно!
Единственное, что их может отличать, - то, что эта активити создана после обновления Android Studio до версии 0.8.11, больше разницы никакой. Откуда это провисание по времени, не понятно.

Кто сталкивался с данными проблемами?

Comment: Думаю, дело в чтении ответа от сервера:

    //получаем ответ от сервера 
    String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);

Comment: Нет, до ответа дело не доходит. В том то и дело, что до того, как войти в процедуру doInBackground, проходит какая-то пауза, а потом уже мгновенно получаю ответ и читаю его.
Т.е. когда я создаю экземпляр:

    new SendParamToURL(callBackSend, URL, process).execute(ListParam);

по точке останова я перехожу в конструктор класса, после конструктора я долден попасть в процедуру doInBackground, для выполнения основного действия (отправки запроса), как правило, это происходит мгновенно, но тут идет пауза в 15 секунд и только потом уже входит в нужную процедуру.
На другом телефоне такой проблемы нет

Comment: попробуй запускать таск так: new SendParamToURL(callBackSend, URL, process).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ListParam);

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло! :)

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что в это время еще работает другая таска.
Таски хоть и работают в другой нити, но все в одной и последовательно, если при их запуске не выставить флаг AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. Тогда каждая будет работать в отдельной нити, и они не будут мешать друг другу. Но это с апи 11, кажется.